# Return values to tkinter interface

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to create an excel like interface in python using tkinter which i have created as shown below.

```
from tkinter import *

window=Tk()

x = [1,2,3,4]

height = 1
width = 4
for i in range(height):  # Rows
    for j in range(width):  # Columns
        b = Entry(window, text="")
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
window.mainloop()
```

How could i return the list x to the tkinter interface? preferably 1 number per cell. Is that possible?

expected result to look something like:
[image]

Comment: Can you show expected result?

Comment: @Alderven i added a photo. I just want to return the list x to the cells

Comment: Your use of the word "return" is a bit confusing. It sounds like you're asking how to _insert_ the data into the widgets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `entry` value using `insert`:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]

height = 1
for i in range(height):
    for j, val in enumerate(x):
        b = Entry(window)
        b.insert(0, val)
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
window.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This works for this specific case, but you have no way of getting the values out, or putting different values in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to emulate a spreadsheet, you need a way to address the widgets in every row. Once you have that, inserting, deleting, and fetching the data becomes very simple.

The simplest way to do that is to store references to the entry widgets as a list of lists, so that you can reference any cell by its row and column number.

```
cells = []
for i in range(height):  # Rows
    row = []
    cells.append(row)
    for j in range(width):  # Columns
        b = Entry(window, text="")
        b.grid(row=i, column=j)
        row.append(b)
```

You can now use `cells` to reference any widget. For example, the widget for row 0, column 2 would be `cells[0][2]`.

With this basic structure, you can now easily write functions to get or set whole rows or whole regions at a time.

For example, here's a way to create a `set_row` function:

```
def set_row(rownum, data):
    row = cells[rownum]
    for entry, value in zip(row, data):
        entry.delete(0, "end")
        entry.insert(0, value)
```

For example, to set the first (0) row with the contents of `x` you could do:

```
set_row(0, x)
```

Getting data from the spreadsheet is also simple:

```
def get_data():
    rows = []
    for rownum in range(height):
        row = []
        rows.append(row)
        for columnnum in range(width):
            entry = cells[rownum][columnnum]
            row.append(entry.get())
    return rows
```

Comment: Simple and elegant.  Breaking out the object generation from the data management, way to show good manageable code development.